# Javascript namespace issue, how do i get this value within this function call

Tags: javascript, jquery

im just not sure how to get the desired value within this function Thanks!

```
temp = exotics[i].split(',');

if ($.inArray(temp[0], tblProbables) != -1) {
    item = $("<li><a id='" + temp[0] + "'" + "href='#' >" + temp[1] + "</a></li>");
    item.click(function () { GetProbable(temp[0]); });
}
```

temp[0] is blank because it doesn't exist within that function space.... so how can i setup the click event so that it calls the function with the proper param?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have a feeling you're reusing the `temp` variable somehow.

If so, you can just create a new variable scope in a function that returns a function that references the proper scoped variable.

```
function createHandler( temp ) {
    return function () { GetProbable(temp); };
}

item.click( createHandler(temp[0]) );
```

Comment: Thank you very much... i'm sad i didn't think of that :P

Answer (score 1):

Store the value in a temporary variable:

```
....
    var temp0 = temp[0];
    item.click(function () { GetProbable(temp0); });
```

If the the `temp0` varible changes multiple times (e.g. in a loop), create a closure:

```
    (function(temp0){ //Inside this function, it doesn't matter if `temp` changes
        item.click(function () { GetProbable(temp0); });
    })(temp[0]);
```

Comment: is there a way that i can set this up so that it doesnt automatically call the last function? I want, on click, to call the GetProbable function... not call it immediately

Comment: @Zholen My suggested code (last line) binds an `onclick` handler in a closure. It's exactely same as your current code, except for the fix of `temp[0]`.

Comment: Oh i totally missed that, i kept thinking the closure was inside the click.